# Schwartz Space Distribution property

Tags: functional-analysis

Hello everybody I am wondering is this property true?

$\forall\psi\in S(\mathbb{R}^{n})\,\forall T\in S'(\mathbb{R}^{n})\,\psi T(\phi)=T(\psi\phi)\,\forall\phi\in S(\mathbb{R}^{n})$

I thinks it works for sure with  T the dirac distribution or the fourier transform.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Isn't it by definition of the product of a distribution by a smooth function?

Comment: Well in my course I have only the definition of a distribution by a polynomial function not a function of S

Comment: Actually it is true by definition for the fourier transform and for the dirac distribution it a property i think but in general the property is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, if $T\in \mathscr S'$ and $\varphi\in\mathscr S$, the distribution $\varphi T$ is defined as
$$
(\varphi T)(\psi)=T(\varphi\psi).
$$